# Classpath including JAR within a JAR

Tags: java, classpath

Is it possible to specify a Java `classpath` that includes a JAR file contained within another JAR file?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you're trying to create a single jar that contains your application and its required libraries, there are two ways (that I know of) to do that.  The first is [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/), which uses a special classloader to allow the nesting of jars.  The second is [UberJar](http://classworlds.codehaus.org/uberjar.html), (or [Shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)), which explodes the included libraries and puts all the classes in the top-level jar.

I should also mention that UberJar and Shade are plugins for Maven1 and Maven2 respectively.  As mentioned below, you can also use the assembly plugin (which in reality is much more powerful, but much harder to properly configure).

Comment: So here we are, 5 years later. It looks like this is still true. Very sad :(

Comment: The best way I know of now-a-days is to use IntelliJ jar artifact. It extracts all of the classes from the dependant jars and puts them in your one jar.

Comment: Thats not possible in some situations like when your using JCE implementations like BouncyCastle that needs to be signed

Comment: I know I've done this before -- years and years ago in Java 1.5 -- it didn't seem that hard then, just obscure. -- Now I need to re-figure out how I did that. -- Seems this isn't the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 ... What are you trying to do?  I think One-Jar's classloader and packager is still the answer to including a Jar within a Jar (for Java SE) projects.  Using UberJar eliminates the problem by extracting class files into your Jar.

Comment: The UberJar link needs login credentials. Is there any successor webpage?

Comment: @enl8enmentnow how can you do this in IntelliJ?

Comment: @StealthRabbi This is how, it's pretty amazing for the rare times you need to do this: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/

Comment: Another +1 for One-Jar. Grab the ant-task distro and wire it into your builds. Takes 5 minutes and works as advertised.

Comment: I happened to be working on a project where writing a script to do this was beneficial. It explodes all jars in a lib folder and puts them in with your top-level jar. Here's a gist of the script:
https://gist.github.com/prmichaelsen/334c4928ba8d75cfbddecc048f070d13

Comment: @debuti how would one solve this problem when you do have bouncyCastle?

Comment: @T3rm1 so we are in 2020 and it is still true :(

Comment: SpringBoot fat jar are have jars inside the main jar. The key is to find to be able to reference a fat jar in a classpath...

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis in 2022 I was able to do this in Eclipse -> project -> export -> runnable jar file -> lets you choose whether you want to include the jar (but you'll have to manually handle the classloader) or explode it (which worked for me)

Answer (score 53):

You do NOT want to use those "explode JAR contents" solutions.  They definitely make it harder to see stuff (since everything is exploded at the same level).  Furthermore, there could be naming conflicts (should not happen if people use proper packages, but you cannot always control this).

The feature that you want is one of the [top 25 Sun RFEs](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/top25_rfes.do): [RFE 4648386](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4648386), which Sun, in their infinite wisdom, has designated as being of low priority. We can only hope that Sun wakes up...

In the meanwhile, the best solution that I have come across (which I wish that Sun would copy in the JDK) is to use the custom class loader [JarClassLoader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php).

Comment: Naming conflicts are actually almost guaranteed to happen with stuff like log4j configuration and license texts.

Comment: Sadly JarClassLoader is GPLv3/commercial so it's probably not going to get "copied by sun (now oracle)", and can't be used commercially unless you have the internal political clout and time to get something purchased. I agree however that jars that barf on the current directory are a bad thing.

Comment: +1 for the idea in this answer (though I won't be +1'ing the answer itself): you can't re-package any signed JAR file, so this technique can't be used in many situations (e.g. Java's `activation.jar`).

Answer (score 35):

After some research I have found method that doesn't require maven or any 3rd party extension/program.

You can use "Class-Path" in your manifest file.

For example:

Create manifest file MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Bundle
Class-Path: ./custom_lib.jar
Main-Class: YourMainClass
```

Compile all your classes and run `jar cfm Testing.jar MANIFEST.MF *.class custom_lib.jar`

`c` stands for create archive
`f` indicates that you want to specify file 
`v` is for verbose input
`m` means that we will pass custom manifest file

Be sure that you included lib in jar package. You should be able to run jar in the normal way.

based on: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things6/

all other information you need about the class-path do you find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: This answer does *not* work. from the oracle doc (linked by banana above): "The Class-Path header points to classes or JAR files on the local network, not JAR files within the JAR file"

Comment: Anything known whether this can also be used in an Android setting.

Comment: It works for executable jar scenario (tested), but it may not work when you want to include a jar in a library jar.

Comment: Oh no it doesn't work, once I moved `custom_lib.jar` away, the jar cannot be executed anymore :(

Comment: How can multiple jars specified in the Class-Path?

Comment: Answer to my question is place space between jar names.

Comment: As stated by @sebnukem above, it doesn't work. It'd be great if it did work, since then, you wouldn't have to use those OneJar and UberJar/Shade stuff or whatever. However, with the new `jpackage` introduced in JDK 14, you can create an installable package which will also include all libraries that you want. And using a `jar` file seems kind of primitive.

Answer (score 23):

Use the **zipgroupfileset** tag (uses same attributes as a **fileset** tag); it will unzip all files in the directory and add to your new archive file.
More information: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html

This is a very useful way to get around the jar-in-a-jar problem -- I know because I have googled this exact StackOverflow question while trying to figure out what to do. If you want to package a jar or a folder of jars into your one built jar with Ant, then forget about all this classpath or third-party plugin stuff, all you gotta do is this (in Ant):

```
<jar destfile="your.jar" basedir="java/dir">
  ...
  <zipgroupfileset dir="dir/of/jars" />
</jar>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are building with ant (I am using ant from eclipse), you can just add the extra jar files
by saying to ant to add them...
Not necessarily the best method if you have a project maintained by multiple people but it works for one person project and is easy.

for example my target that was building the .jar file was:

```
<jar destfile="${plugin.jar}" basedir="${plugin.build.dir}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Author" value="ntg"/>
        ................................
        <attribute name="Plugin-Version" value="${version.entry.commit.revision}"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

I just added one line to make it:

```
<jar ....">
    <zipgroupfileset dir="${external-lib-dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    <manifest>
        ................................
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

where

```
<property name="external-lib-dir" 
          value="C:\...\eclipseWorkspace\Filter\external\...\lib" />
```

was the dir with the external jars.
And that's it...

Answer (score 6):

Not without writing your own class loader.  You can add jars to the jar's classpath, but they must be co-located, not contained in the main jar.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a custom class-loader to do this or a third-party library that supports this. Your best bet is to extract the jar from the runtime and add them to the classpath (or have them already added to the classpath).

Answer (score 2):

I use maven for my java builds which has a plugin called the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

It does what your asking, but like some of the other suggestions describe - essentially exploding all the dependent jars and recombining them into a single jar

Comment: The Maven assembly plugin is pretty painful to use ... UberJar and Shade are Maven1 and Maven2 plugins (a fact I should have mentioned above, and will do so now)

Answer (score 2):

If you have eclpise IDE, you just need to export your JAR and choose "Package Required libraries into generated JAR". eclipse will automatically add the required dependant JARs into the generated JAR as well as generated some eclipse custom class loader that load these JARs automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to advise to extract all the files at the same level, then to make a jar out of the result, since the package system should keep them neatly separated.
That would be the manual way, I suppose the tools indicated by Steve will do that nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Winstone is pretty good http://blog.jayway.com/2008/11/28/executable-war-with-winstone-maven-plugin/. But not for complex sites. And that's a shame because all it takes is to include the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a very easy way if you're using Eclipse.

Export your project as a "Runnable" Jar file (right-click project folder from within Eclipse, select "Export..."). When you configure the export settings, be sure to select "Extract required libraries into generated Jar." Keep in mind, select "Extract..." and **not** "Package required libraries...".

**Additionally**: You must select a run-configuration in your export settings. So, you could always create an empty main( ) in some class and use it for your run configuration.

Anyway, it isn't *guaranteed* to work 100% of the time - as you will notice a pop-up message telling you to make sure you check the licenses of the Jar files you're including and something about not copying signature files. However, I have been doing this for **years** and have never encountered a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Spring Boot, you may want to have a look at this documentation: [The Executable Jar Format](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html)

> **Java does not provide any standard way** to load nested jar files (that
> is, jar files that are themselves contained within a jar). This can be
> problematic if you need to distribute a self-contained application
> that can be run from the command line without unpacking.
>
> To solve this problem, many developers use **“shaded” jars**. A shaded jar
> packages all classes, from all jars, into a single “uber jar”. The
> problem with shaded jars is that it becomes hard to see which
> libraries are actually in your application. It can also be problematic
> if the same filename is used (but with different content) in multiple
> jars. **Spring Boot takes a different approach and lets you actually
> nest jars directly**.

The Spring documentation also lists some *alternative single Jar solutions*:

- [Apache Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)
- [JDotSoft JarClassLoader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php)
- [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/)
- [Shadow Plugin (Gradle)](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/)

Answer (score 0):

Extracting into an Uber-dir works for me as we s should all be using root:\java and have outlets code in packages with versioning. Ie ca.tecreations-1.0.0. Signing is okay because the jars are intact from their downloaded location. 3rd party signatures intact, extract to c:\java. There’s my project dir. run from launcher so java -cp c:\java Launcher

Comment: So jars in c:\java\jars. Source, binaries and resources in c:\java. Exclude backups,properties, keystore_private. Unpack to c:\java and run with classpath forming tool, so maybe ca.tecreations.system.tools.SystemTool or comparable java class. Execute that.

Comment: I have working code for anyone seeking a solution to this problem. Please contact tim.devries@yahoo.ca. I guess I could say, you can attempt to download from tecreations.ca/java/downloads/release/ and then attempt to run ca.tecreations.launcher.Launcher, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use one jar and many libraries in separate jars, not in a single jar. Use separate jar from jar libraries.
Suppose you have such a folder structure:

```
path/yourApp/yourApp.jar
path/yourApp/lib/lib1.jar
path/yourApp/lib/megalib1.jar
path/yourApp/lib/supermegalib1.jar
```

All you have to do, add each of used jar to your **MANIFEST.MF**.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.company.MyProgram
Class-Path: ./lib/lib1.jar ./lib/megalib1.jar ./lib/supermegalib1.jar
```

So, in the manifest, you grant usage to each library.
Single file "all in one jar" might be easier to share and distribute, but not significantly. It will not make your program easier to maintain, and will not make your program to run faster. It will not make significant hdd usage difference. Just distribute as zip and unpack where it needs to be deployed.