# Class not found javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I have problem with creating executable jar file. I creating the jar file by Intellij idea X artifacts. But when I try to execute this jar, it gave me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityNotFoundException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I check which package contains this class and I found it in this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I check if the Intellij add this jar to my executable jar and I found it there. So have someone any Idea where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` contains this class.

It might be a classpath issue. Are you including required jar libraries in your jar? Can your app access other application provided jars at runtime? You may find the answers to this question useful: [Classpath including JAR within a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar)

Comment: Yes I checked that, 1) I check in maven site: <a>http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C4%7Cfc%3Ajavax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException</a>
2) By unzip this package.

Comment: I doesn't usage **org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:3.3.1.GA**
I usage **org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final**

Comment: Yes I can reference to it from my IDE. Next I tried extract the content of jar, which Intellij build for me and then I extract the **org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final** jar file. I browse to it content and found this class.

Comment: I create own **EntityNotFoundException** class, and now I have the same error but with another class, the class is now: **org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext**

Comment: @pierretautou What kind of executable jar are you producing? Does it have nested jars with the dependencies (library jars inside your app jar). If this is the case, take a look at the related question I posted in this answer, and also take a look at [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php) and other tools mentioned in the related question.

Comment: I actually have three maven modules: persistence, domain, app. The dependencies are: persistence using domain and app using persistence. So I trying to create jar from app, which using persistence and domain dependencies. Each from this dependencies using some maven dependencies, which all of this I include in jar.

Comment: @pierretautou What I'm trying to tell you is that if your executable JAR `app.jar` has nested JARs (i.e. `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar` is inside `app.jar`), it won't be possible to locate any of `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar`'s classes at runtime unless you write your own classloader, or use a tool that provides it, such as [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: javaee-api-5.0-2.jar to your project.

Answer (score 0):

The JPA libs are a separate external download from Oracle. You may need to download them separately and install them into your local Maven repo.

You should also be specifying a version in your dependency XML.

Comment: Yes I did in this way. The version I have specified in parent pom.xml.