# maven-dependency-plugin generates duplicate files in jar-with-dependencies.jar file

Tags: java, maven-2, jar, packaging, maven-dependency-plugin

i am creating a standalone java application with maven, and i am including the dependencies in the jar file with **maven-dependecy-plugin** as follows:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>theMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-my-bundle</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                     <configuration>
                       <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                       </descriptorRefs>

                     </configuration>
                    </execution>
               </executions>
        </plugin>
```

this includes the dependencies in the generated jar file in a lib folder, and the jar runs and works fine, but the issue is in the other generated jar file `appname-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

**ISSUE:** i am not sure if it's an issue or not, but i noticed in target folder in the generated `appname-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`, that it contains duplicate application files like:

1. all sql,property files,xml files exists twice.
2. all java classes .class file exists twice.
3. there are lots of overview.html and license.txt files related to the dependencies.

i am not sure if that's feels right or not, also i need someone to clarify for me what is the importance of this generated jar file, since i am not familiar with this plugin.

please advise, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "exist twice"? Two files cannot have the same path--what are the complete paths you're seeing? The plugin creates a jar file with all the project dependencies in it, so it can run standalone--not sure why else you'd use it; why did you *start* using it?

Comment: when i view this jar with win rar, i can see for example two copies for each .sql,.xml file in my application.

Comment: and i am using it because i want to make a standalone application with all dependencies inside it, is that a bad practice ? or should i use another plugin ?

Comment: That's what the plugin is for. Regarding double files--I'm asking what the complete path is, because two files cannot have the same name.

Comment: i can't tell the path,double files are inside the jar file, for example on the root of the jar file when you view it with winrar you will find two files named mydata.sql

Comment: @DaveNewton -- MahmoudS is exactly correct. The JAR format can hold duplicates files (exact same path & name), and this is a known issue with maven-assembly-plugin. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308916/maven-generates-duplicate-pom-xml-and-pom-properties-files-in-a-jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have mentioned [jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies), I assume you are using [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to assemble your project artifacts along with the dependant jars into a single jar.

I suspect that your project artifacts are getting into the jar-with-dependencies twice - due to a property `useProjectArtifact` of [dependencySet](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet) which is `true`, by default.  You can set this property to true in your assembly descriptor and see if it addresses your issue.

In the specific case above, maven dependency plugin does not seem to be doing anything useful.  maven assembly plugin automatically packages all its dependencies into a single distribution as per configuration.

But do note [classpath issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar) if you create an executable jar-with-dependencies.  You may want to create a `zip` or `tar.gz` instead.

The configuration used above is the default and does not allow for customization. You may want to use an assembly descriptor file, where you can set the property mentioned earlier or other options.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to mention that i am using the maven-assembly-plugin along with the maven-dependecy-plugin, i updated the code, do i have to use the assembly plugin along with dependency plugin to get my dependencies in the project jar ?

Comment: @Msaleh.  Updated answer to address the queries.

Comment: what can i see is that maven dependency plugin gather all jars and put them in a lib folder inside the application jar, so it does something useful here. and can you please guide me to a better configuration to gather all pom jars in the application generated jar ?