# Maven generates duplicate pom.xml and pom.properties files in a jar

Tags: java, maven

I package my Maven-based Spring app with:

```
mvn install-DskipTests -Peverything.
```

And something strange arises. In META-INF of generated jar, I find duplicate pom.xml and pom.properties files. Can someone explain it? Thanks.

[image]

Here is extracted pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>migrate-app</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>migrate-app</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>

..

</dependencies>

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>everything</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>          
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>            
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Output for command:

```
mvn -version
```

> Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 15:44:56+0700)
>   Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin..
>   Java version: 1.6.0_30, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
>   Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
>   OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"

Comment: Could you please write here the output for the "mvn -version" ?

Comment: thanks. I will search for it too. I run mvn version 3 here and I had the same behaviour. double files inside the jar.

Comment: Same here! I've also found these files duplicated few time using same Maven version. It didn't actually fuss me, because everything works fine, but it's really weird.

Answer (score 19):

Add

```
<build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
         <archive>
           <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
         </archive>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

to your pom.xml

Comment: Maven build adds maven files into META-INF folder. If you are developing an applet or similar project, this is a problem. addMavenDescriptor property excludes maven files from jar when false.

Comment: Just ran into this error with a project containing an applet. It's clearly related to m2e. I finally removed the maven descriptors that seems to be the only solution for that bug... -thanks

Answer (score 15):

It seems like this is a somewhat common problem that arises from a conflict in Eclipse, especially with the *m2e-wtp* integration.

Some people are indicating that it can be fixed by including *clean* in the list of goals to run, e.g. `mvn clean package`.

Also try to update your *m2e* installation and make sure you don't have multiple versions of *m2e* or *m2eclipse* (the pre-Indigo version) installed.

Some references to other people facing this problem:

- http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg01995.html
- https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MECLIPSEWTP-209
- https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2349
- https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-extras/issues/9

Comment: I opened http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSHARED-324 to track the issue on the maven-archiver plugin. Anyone interested in seeing a fix in Maven should vote for it.

Comment: I just closed this issue because it is fixed implicitly by Maven JAR Plugin 2.6.

Answer (score 7):

I know this issue is a bit old, but I thought I'd share an obscure bit of information on this subject.  I was running across the same issue, and I found that when I ran maven with Eclipse open, AND my workspace preferences were set to refresh the workspace using native hooks or polling, the extra pom.xml and pom.properties files were added by eclipse!  Closing eclipse or removing the refresh workspace option solved the problem for me.  This was a hard one to track down, so hopefully someone else will benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up to @Dan's work around:

I tried your solution and it *appears* to work -- at first blush.  However, it's just delaying the eventual failure.

It appears than anytime the workspace is refreshed the pom.xml and pom.properties files are created in the /classes directory.  After that any later "package" goal will include the duplicate files in the .jar and thus break any later signing.

If the polling is on - you "fail-fast".  If it's off you can fail at arbitrary times in future builds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do "mvn clean" and the  do "mvn package" after that   or just do "mvn clean package". if "mvn clean" fails due to any reason and if you do "mvn package" after that , you will see this issue again.

Answer (score -5):

Not sure what you mean by `duplicate` but the jar created by maven does come with `pom.xml` and `pom.properties` in `META-INF` folder.  See [this section](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR) of the maven getting started guide.

Comment: I mean that there're two pom.xml files and two pom.properties files.

Comment: Jar archives are based on a ZIP format (in fact, you can manipulate jar archive with ZIP utilities) which kinda allows duplicate entries in archive. Entries with the same name are simply overwritten during extraction process. When you inspect jar file built with Eclipse/m2e combo you will see literally duplicate entries for the files mentioned. What is really annoying is that this breaks jar cmdline tool (you can't update any file)