# Eclipse maven-jar-plugin not signing, because of duplicate entries pom.xml and pom.properties only on Windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, maven, jar, code-signing

I searched a lot, but I have not found any solution for this.

### *Environment*

```
*** Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Release - Build id: 20130614-0229 with m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP
1.0.0.20130612-1742 
*** Windows 7 up to date
*** Java SDK 1.7.0-40
*** Maven: Embedded (3.0.4/1.4.0.20130531-2315)
```

## Problem

### Errors:

Signing jars with *(apache)maven-**jar**-plugin:2.4:sign (**signing**)* on Linux works fine! The same maven project on Windows leads to the following error:

```
[INFO] jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)
[ERROR] jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/maven/.../pom.xml
```

### Other messages:

I spotted different outputs between Linux and Windows from *(apache)maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (**default-jar**)*

Linux-Eclipse skips both files, because were already added:

```
...
[INFO] META-INF/maven/com.xyz/abc-client/pom.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/com.xyz/abc-client/pom.properties already added, skipping
...
```

after that the signing works fine!

**The Windows ouput is not showing these two lines!!**

### Additional Information:

- I can not use the *(apache)maven-**jarsigner**-plugin*, because it will lead to following error - without solution:

  ```
  [ERROR] jarsigner: cannot rename file jarfile.jar to .orig`
  ```
- This [github-forum](https://github.com/tesla/m2eclipse-extras/issues/9) website tells me that the m2e-wtp-plugin of
  Eclipse causing the problem, and that I should **use maven on command
  line** .... this is the absolutely **last option** to use!!!
- There is also a **[bug "MPIR-286"](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPIR-286)** on codehouse for this, but still unresolved.
- The clean part is done by the plugin and it's the same configuration for a client-module build before the one causing the problem.

## Question:

Is there a possibility to get rid of this error? I cannot use the jarsigner-plugin, because of the "rename"-error and not the jar-plugin, because of the "duplicate entry"-error ... that is in fact a very strange situation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<sub>**This is the solution by the question's author, moved to the appropriate section.

To question's author: if you want to gain reputation, feel free to write a new answer, then ping me to remove this answer.**</sub>

So I found it out myself. Here is what helped me to fix the problem.

### Research

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308916/maven-generates-duplicate-pom-xml-and-pom-properties-files-in-a-jar) after more research and they stated, that the maven.archiver is the cause, because it wants to create the both files after they have been copied into the jar from m2e.mavenarchiver-plugin.

*"... the m2e.mavenarchiver is creating pom.xml files etc. in the target directory, then these get pulled in by the maven archiver maven plugin, which then also creates its own files - hence the duplicates."*

So the solution is also stated on this topic site.

### Solution

Add

```
 <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
     <archive>
       <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
     </archive>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

to your pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

In my case 
`maven clean install` fixed this issues

Make use of [this Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/)
 for Viewing the jar whether it has a Duplicate pom.xml and properties

Answer (score 0):

I have added below plugin that worked :

```
<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
     <archive>
         <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
     </archive>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```