# htmlunit-driver 2.26 has duplicate pom

Tags: maven, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I am reffering to following pom entry for dependencies of [htmlunit-driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/htmlunit-driver/2.27).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
```

But while packaging it with a JNLP file, I am getting following error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-6:jnlp-inline (package) on project : Error while updating manifest of unprocessed_htmlunit-driver__V2.27.jar: duplicate entry: META-INF/maven/org.seleniumhq.selenium/htmlunit-driver/pom.xml -> [Help 1]

Investigating further I found that the [htmlunit-driver-2.27.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/htmlunit-driver/2.27) file contains two `pom.properties` and `pom.xml`.

[image]

Please help me to solve the issue:

1. Should I rectify the JAR and use my own version .
2. Is there any maven plugin available which can automatically resolve such corrupted JAR files.
3. Any other available option.

Comment: How exactly are you packaging it?

Comment: I am using webstart-maven-plugin for packaging .Although , everything was working fine till 2.21 version of this jar, but it broke when I upgraded to 2.27 version of the jar . The jar file available in maven central is incorrect  , you may download and check the same.

Comment: You're right, those jars are busted. Are using a repository manager? I would repair the jar that you want (un-jar, remove duplicates and re-jar) and deploy it your repository manager with a different version - say 2.27.FIX or something like that

Comment: Yes Steve , thanks for the suggestion , as of now I am doing the same .

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of Eclipse/maven conflict as hinted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10308916/184201).

Since `2.27` was released, it can't be changed, but [2.28-snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/seleniumhq/selenium/htmlunit-driver/2.28-SNAPSHOT/htmlunit-driver-2.28-20170613.110230-1.jar) was just deployed, if you can use it.

Otherwise, you can manually make your own version.

Regarding the next releases, `mven clean` should always precede `deploy`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ahmed. I am manually fixing them and keeping my own version .