# how to place all jar files in one jar file?

Tags: java, build, jar

is it possible to build a jar file made up of all jar files that I need? I am building my project and the jar files are not being included in the generated jar file and I would like to  generate one separate jar file which contains all jar files in this project

Comment: take a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar

Comment: *"is it possible to build a jar file made up of all jar files that I need?"* It is generally better to include a manifest in the main Jar which identifies the dependent Jars by relative paths.  Why do you not implement that strategy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are Eclipse plugins that can do that [FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/), [JarsSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You can't include jars in a jar in order to have them on the classpath (you can put them in the jar, but you can't use them as dependencies)

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), however, gives you an alternative with the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). It unpacks all jars and stores their .class files in your new, single jar. There are, of course, other options to do the same thing, but maven is a great build tool to use anyway.

Comment: *"Not possible. You can't include jars in a jar."*  Sure you can.  Whether it can be made to work at run-time is a separate matter.  On that matter, I ***believe*** there are also custom class loaders that can load resources from within Jar inside other Jars.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. You can put them in, of course, but you can't use them. The classloader is a good idea, do you have a link perhaps?

Comment: I thought you might ask that.  ;)  A quick search on "jar class loader" shows ..a lot of dross, but in the 1st 5 hits is a link to .. 'One Jar', as mentioned by evanwong.  *"One-JAR provides custom classloader that knows how to load classes and resources from a jars inside an archive, instead of from jars in the filesystem."* :)

Answer (score 0):

The [yguard tool](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.html) can do this. It can also shrink your code and obfuscate it if you wish.

Here is an ant example from their documentation:

```
  <taskdef name="yguard" classname="com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask" classpath="buildlib/yguard.jar"/>

  <inoutpairs resources="auto">
    <fileset dir="${input-lib-dir}">
      <include name="myapp*.jar"/>
      <exclude name="*_obf.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <mapper type="glob" from="*.jar" to="*_obf.jar"/>
  </inoutpairs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at onejar:
http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: One-JAR is no longer maintained. I am maintaining a partly modernized fork at https://github.com/nsoft/uno-jar

Answer (score 0):

You can use one jar maven plug in.

```
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <!--                   REPOSITORIES                          -->
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
            <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
            <!--                      ONE JAR PLUGIN                     -->
            <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.acme.MainClass</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
                <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Optional -->
                            <onejarVersion>0.97</onejarVersion>
                            <!--
                                Optional, use only if you need to include native libraries
                                (dll's) <binlibs> <fileSet>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/dllextract</directory>
                                <includes> <include>test.dll</include> </includes> </fileSet>
                                </binlibs>
                            -->
                            <!-- Optional, default is false -->
                            <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
                            <!-- Optional, default is "onejar" -->
                            <classifier>onejar</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>one-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```