# How to import jar of jars

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Classpath including JAR within a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar)

I would like to know if it is possible to import a jar of jars. I am trying to load [`openehr_ref_impl_java-1.0.1.jar`](http://www.openehr.org/wiki/display/projects/Java+Project+Download) which is a jar of jars, but the instances of classes aren`t being referenced. First I copy the jar to the lib folder(located in my project folder) -> right click -> build path -> add to build path.

I tried unzipping the .jar file which works - the classes are referenced, but I figured since there is also a jar of jars for the javadoc (openehr_ref_impl_java-1.0.1_javadocs.jar), there might be 
a simpler solution.

Comment: did  you try `java -jar openehr_ref_impl_java-1.0.1.jar`? may be its self-exploding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked also offers the component Jars.  The implication is that the 'one Jar of all components' is simply for convenience of distribution/download.

So the answer would be:-  Extract the Jars first, add each to the compile/run-time class-path as you would for any regular Jar.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded it. Project name (right click) -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jars -> Your Jar of Jars.

It works for me.

Comment: I tried that, but if I try to import something like "import se.acode.openehr.parser;" it does not see it.

Comment: I can see it now, you're right.