# Error: Could not find or load main class ExampleScenario

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to create an Ant build script in order to build an executable JAR for a small program I wrote. In particular, this small program uses an external JAR `selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar`, which is stored in the `lib` directory in my project's root directory, while the source java files `ExampleScenario.java` and `ExampleClass.java` are defined in `src/com/selenium/example`.

So far, I have the following build.xml defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="SampleDemo" default="jar">

<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
<property name="bin.dir" value="bin"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
<property name="dist.dir" value="dist"/>
<property name="com.dir" value="com"/>
<property name="selenium.dir" value="${com.dir}/selenium"/>
<property name="example.dir" value="${selenium.dir}/example"/>

<target name="clean" description="Delete all generated files">
    <delete dir="${bin.dir}" failonerror="false"/>
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" failonerror="false"/>
</target>

<target name="compile" description="">
    <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}/${example.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}/${example.dir}" destdir="${bin.dir}/${example.dir}" classpath="${lib.dir}/selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" description="JARS the Task" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}"/>

    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${bin.dir}/${example.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="ExampleScenario"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lib.dir}/selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar; "/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

The main method is located within the ExampleScenario class. When I try to run the output JAR file, however, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ExampleScenario
```

As a beginner to ANT scripting, I've read over the ANT documentation and have followed some tutorials online. I've also tried looking online for answers regarding this particular issue, but I haven't been able to figure out what is causing this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Issue has been solved, but my external JAR appears not to be recognized:

ERROR LOG:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

EDIT: The previous issue has been resolved by moving the created JAR file to the root directory of my project. It seems that directories defined in the manifest file are relative to your current directory. Since my lib directory exists in the root directory of my project and not in the dist directory, it makes sense why the aforementioned error was being thrown. More information is provided in the following link:

[Java NoClassDefFoundError when running jar containing library jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668454/java-noclassdeffounderror-when-running-jar-containing-library-jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest Main-Class needs the package information as well, just like any any main method to run using java. Try with below.

```
manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.selenium.example.ExampleScenario"/>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lib.dir}/selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar; "/>
</manifest>
```

Update - selenium-java jars are missing. Please add them. [Download it from here](http://seleniumhq.com)

Comment: Thanks. My JAR file executes now, but I get an error claiming that classes that are supposed to be defined in my external JAR are not defined. I was wondering if you would happen to know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: aah. Should have noticed it, my bad. You do not have the complete jars of selenium, try loading all the jars from a lib folder. Take a look at this "http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-java-2.35.0.zip"

Comment: Hmm...nvm...I figured out why this was happening. The exact answer was given on this page:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668454/java-noclassdeffounderror-when-running-jar-containing-library-jar