# Running jar file using classpath

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file which includes the manifest entry to the main class and I was trying to run the jar using the -jar option and then came to know that using the -jar option ignores the classpath setting.

Previous Usage: `java -jar MyJar.jar`

Now I have all my rest of the jars configured in `$CLASSPATH`.

How do I include the same while running my jar.

BTW I'm running on a Linux OS.

Comment: In fact sun/oracle have been trying to simplify this for last 11 years: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4648386

Comment: Do any of your classes include a package declaration? This is important!

Comment: @diegoaguilar : Yes my classes are housed in a package and in my manifest.txt file the main class attribute is defined as follows `Main:Class: MyJar.HelloWorld`

Answer (score 1):

java -cp $CLASSPATH -jar MyJar.jar

Comment: It gives me an error saying `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Message` but I see that the mail.jar is present in my $CLASSPATH. Is there anything I need to modify to refer the dependent jars.

Comment: are you 100% sure that all needed jars are in the $CLASSPATH directory?  If on Windows, beware of "\" as a path separator.  Try setting CLASSPATH with forward slashes, e.g. CLASSPATH=c:/foo;c:/bar

Comment: Yes all jar files are on the CLASSPATH variable and a part of the CLASSPATH is as follows `:/dirjar/adv/lib/log4j.jar:/dirjar/adv/lib/mail.jar:`.What is wrong here. BTW as I mentioned it is Linux OS.

Comment: If you insist on setting the classpath the way you described in your question, here is the workaround (It's valid only for jdk6 and above) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Comment: The version of java in my server is `1.5.0_06` is there any other way to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach (provided you are familiar with ant scripts) would be to create a build script to generate an executable jar. You can define a compile rule, a rule to create an executable jar that has other jars (in exploded format) contained within it.

Please note that there is no standard way to include a jar within a jar. [Classpath including JAR within a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar)

I have already done something similar here you might want to have a look the [ant build file](https://github.com/anupamsaini/Trie/blob/master/src/build.xml)