# Storm Rabbitmq exception while running from console

Tags: rabbitmq

I am running a storm topology from command prompt using the command :
bin/storm jar /home/stormrabbitmqtest.jar RabbitmqTopology rabbittest

The topology consists of a spout which is reading from a rabbitmq queue. But i am getting the exception below:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rabbitmq/client/Consumer
    at RabbitmqTopology.main(RabbitmqTopology.java:17)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rabbitmq.client.Consumer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
I am not able to understand the issue. Looking forward for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html

Download the java client and add  `rabbitmq-client.jar` in your class-path

Comment: I have already included the dependent jar file in stormrabbitmqtest.jar and still getting the exception.

Comment: did you create a single jar ? Could you try to leave the dependent outside the jar a use the class path? .. this is a typical call-path error.

Comment: I have a created a single jar 'stormrabbitmqtest.jar' that also includes the dependent jar files. I am not specifying classpath while running the topology from the console.

Comment: I don't know exactly how you have created your single jar, but it's if you create a jar it is not autamatically load the dependency.
For example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar