# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. - Using a library with another library

Tags: java, classpath, libraries

I've created a library, let's call it `MyLib`. This library, `MyLib`, uses `Google Guava` library, so I've `Guava`'s jar in the library folder that belongs to `MyLib`.

Now I've created a new project where I'll use `MyLib`. I've imported `MyLib` to my project and when I run it I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus
    at com.dwnz.mylib.<init>(SchoolBus.java:29)
    at com.dwnz.mylib.getAsyncBusToMainThread(SchoolBus.java:61)
    at view.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:91)
    at view.MainFrame.newInstance(MainFrame.java:586)
    at view.Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
Java Result: 1
```

I've googled and I found out that on run time `JVM` can't load the class. If I add Google's Guava jar as library to my project I don't get this exception.

What I don't understand here is why can't JVM load Guava's class from `MyLib` library if I've added Guava jar to `MyLib` library?
How can I make it work this way? Otherwise I find it a bit pointless to create this library.

I'm using `NetBeans`, if it makes any difference.

Comment: You either use a dependency management tool like maven , or setup the classpath manually to include the guava jars needed at runtime. Either way the classpath governs what jars are loaded at runtime.

Comment: are you using guava directly in your project that uses `MyLib`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classpath including JAR within a JAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar)

Comment: @Xinzz If I dont add the jar from Guava to my project I get that exception. If I do add the guava jars in my project I dont't get the exception.

Comment: that wasn't the question... are you using any of Guava's classes or methods DIRECTLY from the project that uses the library `MyLib`

Comment: @Xinzz No, I'm not. All I call are methods from MyLib

Comment: @Bhaskar can you point me into a tutorial on how to do it? I'm lost here, been googling but I'm afraid I'm not on the right path

Comment: I've came up to this tutorial, quite easy to do my task. http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/39256/add-dependencies-to-maven-pom-xml-file/