# Is it possible to package dependencies in .jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, package

I was wondering if it is possible to "package in" dependencies while using mvn compile.

When I do compile my program with mvn install I do get clean and great result as expected, but after I package it into .jar suddenly I get missing classes exceptions.

I have read that it may be caused by differences in build and package class paths but I am unable to fix it.

[image: Exception screen]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you can use a tool called [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net) or you can generate what's known as a "fat jar", which basically unjars everything and combines into a single jar.  Maven prefers fat jars, I personally don't as I tend to place property/configuration files in the my jars which share the same name, so it screws things up.

Comment: Another approach is to include the `class-path` entry in the manifest file to point to the location of the external libraries, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899985/this-project-cannot-be-added-because-it-does-not-produce-a-jar-file-using-an-ant/24900260#24900260)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: The basic problem is that the default classloaders in the Java runtime library does not support classes in jars inside jars.  Hence a lot of different approaches has been tried.  Either repack all classes in a single jar ("shaded jar") or have Maven create a launcher script with needed files which sets the classpath and run the program.  I prefer the latter for non-trivial things - see http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/assemble-mojo.html

Comment: Also consider just using maven to run your program.  The exec-maven-plugin allows you to run classes with `mvn -q exec:java`.   See https://github.com/ravn/dagger2-hello-world for a tiny example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like an executable shaded jar you're looking for.

How to make executable jar?

https://github.com/renfeng/elo-rating/blob/master/cli/pom.xml#L32-L51

How to make shaded jar?

https://github.com/renfeng/elo-rating/blob/master/cli/pom.xml#L52-L67

Alternatively, you can

1. Package dependencies with assembly plugin, and

https://github.com/renfeng/elo-rating/blob/master/cli/src/main/assembly/dist.xml#L30-L33

2. Launch with class path specified.

https://github.com/renfeng/elo-rating/blob/master/cli/elo#L4

Or, you can settle somewhere in the middle, like my github sample project does.

Comment: Please inline your code.  Always consider that answers should be usable even if printed to paper.