# Java running external jar without IDE?

Tags: java

I've written a java program that reads an excel file with jxl.jar. It's currently working, but I have to use cmd to run the program. Double clicking the jar file does not appear to be working. These are the commands I use to compile and run the code:

```
javac -classpath C:/workspace/jxl.jar:. main.java GUi.java

jar cvfm run.jar manifest.txt Main.class GUI.class GUI$1.class GUI$2.class GUI$3.class Main$1MyCustomTableCellRenderer.class Main$1YourTableCellRenderer.class Main$MyCustomTableCellRenderer.class

java -cp run.jar Main
```

I'm not really sure why it's any different from double clicking it. I've compiled the jxl file into the run.jar file so I don't understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: Take a look at [Working with Manifest Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html), you need to specify a `class-path` and `main-class` entry for it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Jar file in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An Example** directly from *Java Tutorial* on [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) as suggested by @MadProgrammer in his comment.

We want to load classes in `MyUtils.jar` into the class path for use in `MyJar.jar`. These two JAR files are in the same directory.

We first create a text file named `Manifest.txt` with the following contents:

```
Class-Path: MyUtils.jar
```

**Warning:** The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.

---

We then create a JAR file named `MyJar.jar` by entering the following command:

```
jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class
```

This creates the JAR file with a manifest with the following contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: MyUtils.jar
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
```

The classes in `MyUtils.jar` are now loaded into the class path when you run `MyJar.jar`.

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar)

Comment: But I want to be able to run it by just double clicking run.jar. How should I package the manifest?

Comment: you need to add the jar in the final bundled jar. Let me update my post.

Comment: have a look at the example

Answer (score 0):

Try this in command prompt:

Run the below command if you bundled the jar with all libraries

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

If you need to add jars at the time of execution please add all the jars at command line, as follows;

```
java -cp /path/jxl.jar;myJar.jar Class-Name-Main
```