# Specifying a javaagent within the jar file to be run

Tags: java, jar

I'm developing an OpenJPA application (no webserver, regular java se app). In order to make OpenJPA work with my application, I need to set the openjpa-all-2.3.0.jar as a javaagent.

```
java -cp ... -javaagent:/full/path/to/openjpa-all-2.3.0.jar -jar app.jar
```

As I am **packaging the openjpa.jar within the app.jar** anyway, I am now wondering how it is possible to specify the javaagent, as a jar within my application jar file.

This didn't work

```
java -cp ".;.\app.jar" -javaagent:openjpa-all-2.3.0.jar pckg.Main
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classpath including JAR within a JAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar)

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do it.
The JVM does not look at the classpath to find the specified agent; it is expecting a file path, and you also cannot specify file paths inside jar files.

[JDK-4648386](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4648386) is the related feature request, and was closed Won't Fix after 18 years.

However, what you can do is write code to copy the agent jar from a classpath resource to a temporary file, and then attach it to the current running JVM. The [ByteBuddy Agent](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.12.7/index.html?net/bytebuddy/agent/ByteBuddyAgent.html) library provides tooling to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply in your MANIFEST.MF, add this property:
Launcher-Agent-Class: org.path.to.your.AgentClass

Comment: Unfortunately, `Launcher-Agent-Class` only supports a single agent and no option string like the command line does. But there is [Agent Embedder Maven Plugin](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/agent-embedder-maven-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file), which adds those features and even for the simple case (single agent, no argument) just makes it easy to package an agent into your JAR during the build. Maybe, you want to give it a try.