# How do I reference a runtime Maven dependency in the the java CLI?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, instrumentation, javaagents

I need to add an instrumentation JAR to my Java command line. If possible, I want to this argument to reference a JAR included in my Maven dependencies. As an example:

```
java -javaagent:tooling.jar -jar myapplication.jar
```

This "tooling.jar" does not exist as an explicit file in the filesystem. Instead, it is listed as a runtime dependency in Maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
   <artifactId>tooling</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

If it's relevant, I'm using Java 11 and Spring Boot.

The purpose of this is to avoid having to move two separate JAR files to every run environment (for technical reasons I am only able to deploy the application JAR). As far as I can tell there's nothing technically wrong with this approach, as the JAR does exist - it is just wrapped into the application JAR. However, nowhere that I've found has described this process, so I wonder if I'm doing something terribly wrong. I haven't been able to test this yet. Is this a valid pattern and what is the appropriate syntax for it?

Comment: You're trying to unpack an uber jar?

Comment: @Stewart I'm not sure what you mean. All I'm trying to do is reference a packaged dependency (the instrumentation JAR tooling.jar) that is inside the application JAR (packaged by Maven). It's going to take me a while to set up a test case, so I wanted to see if what I was doing was possible and/or recommended. The lack of information on the subject is usually an indicator that the solution is obvious and I'm missing something.

Comment: Does your packaging tool preserve the fully qualified class names, ie, the package names, etc?  If so ... does it work to try `java -javaagent:myapplication.jar -jar myapplication.jar`

Comment: I am unsure how Maven handles the build process regarding class names. I did manage to find a possible-duplicate that indicates what I want is impossible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424364/specifying-a-javaagent-within-the-jar-file-to-be-run

Comment: How about some feedback to my answer? I think it is rather impolite to ask for help in public and then keep your helpers waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a Java agent either via `-javaagent:/my/own/agent.jar` like you already do or during runtime. But in both cases, the agent **has** to be a regular file on a file system. Agents cannot be loaded any other way.

Therefore, either you need to deploy the agent to your target execution environment separately, or you need to bootstrap by extracting it manually from your uber JAR during application start-up and then hot-attach it **before** loading any of the classes you wish to instrument.