# Jar inside a lib project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I wanted to know if it is possible to include an external jar inside my own library project of defined classes. Suppose I am using abc.jar and I have xyz.jar is there a way to pack xyz inside abc? so that my project/application has only one jar on the outside?

Comment: If u use the support jar, you've notice it is working that way already

Comment: Look at this link [Classpath including JAR within a JAR][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just create a Java Project and include all the libraries you wanted to use, build it then copy your built jar and import this to your current project and use it as xyz.* and abc.*.

:)