# running a scala jar containing its dependancies

Tags: scala, jar, classpath

I created a jar with the following structure

`abc.jar
    /--META-INF
       /--MANIFEST.MF
    /--dependancies
       /--depend1.jar
       /--depend2.jar
       /--depend3.jar
    /--com
       /--mycompany
          /--JettyLauncher.class
          /--otherclass.class`

my manifest declares the classpath and the main class as:

`Class-Path: .:./dependancies
Main-Class: com.mycompany.JettyLauncher`

However, if I cannot run this jar with the `scala` command in any way.

If I try running `scala abc.jar`, I get an error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.JettyLauncher`
(which means it did read the manifest!)

If I try running `scala -classpath abc.jar com.mycompany.JettyLauncher`, I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` for one of the classes in the dependant jars.
I assume this is because the -classpath argument overwrote the classpath in the manifest.

I was finally able to run my jar when I pulled the dependancies out of the jar and placing the in a folder next to the abc.jar 
and then `scala -classpath "abc.jar:dependancies/*:." com.mycompany.JettyLauncher` finally worked.

But is there any way to get it working when the dependancies folder is contained in the jar?

Many thanks,

Aliza

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar - I think the safe bet is _not_ to nest jar files. Use a tool such as [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) if you want to create one jar that contains all dependencies. It will detect naming conflicts and allow you to apply appropriate merge strategies.

Comment: thanks, I tried with  gradle-one-jar (https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar) but that didn't work either. When I run `scala abc-standalone.jar` I get an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot in the java.class.path: consider using -Done-jar.jar.path to specify the one-jar filename.` altough the Boot.class is located in the correct location.

Comment: I don't know that tool or Gradle, so cannot comment on that.