# Deploy Eclipse - Error Executing file .jar - Spring Batch

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, spring-batch

I have a program running successfully in ECLIPSE. But when generate the .jar file and try to run it generates an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionException 
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            ... 7 more
```

The class information `org/springframework/batch/core/` it is referenced in the project.

[image]

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: check your classapth of jar file. There are multiple options while creating a jar file through eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to use `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and possibly execute the `spring-boot:repackage` goal. You might do Okay just making it a `.war` file, since that has worked for me with a `Spring Boot` application. The problem with executable jar files Spring style is that java can't load jars from a jar file. There are other non-spring solutions, see, e.g., [Classpath including JAR within a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar), but you should look through the spring docs to figure it out.

Reference: [Packaging executable jar and war files](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging)

Comment: Thank you. I managed to solve. I put the lib in the root of the jar and informed by command and worked beautiful.