# SBT unmanaged jars

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I have a dependency that includes several jar files in the lib folder. When I try to compile my application, it does not find the classes in those jar files.

[image: Dependency in question]

More specifically, it fails to find the classes defined in `polyglot.jar`, with this error:

`Error:scalac: Class polyglot.frontend.JLExtensionInfo not found - continuing with a stub.`

Is there any way to make the included jar files visible on the classpath, without copying them into my own project's `lib` folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you putting a jar inside a jar (looks that way on the screenshot)? That will [never work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar)…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What 0__ said: no, nested jars won't be discovered. There are [some](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4648386) [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar), but they really aren't worth it. If you want the jars as unmanaged dependencies, you'll have to add them to your own `lib/`.