# How to include 3rd party libraries inside the custom library module in android

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-2.1

I'm using android studio 1.5 and  i'm creating general sdk library like paypal/facebook sdk, this plugin include 3rd party library like QRcode scanner,okhttp for networking. Once i include in these plugins inside custom library gradle file it's working fine in the same project structure, But when i  try to include custom sdk library to other android application the above 3rd party plugins not included in the final custom library sdk so how can i build the custom android sdk library with 3rd party libraries.

Comment: It depends how you're integrating your library in an application. If you're including it in the app's `build.gradle` file, all the dependencies it uses will also be imported. But if you're exporting it as a jar, you'll need to include those 3rd party library jars separately or use some tool to include the jars in your own: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/183313/508608

Comment: Hi below is my code snippet dependencies in library gradle file.                                                                   compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1''
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'   once i release this library how can i download these dependencies inside the sdk itself so it won't affect app.

Comment: How are you including your custom sdk library in your application, as a jar or as a gradle dependency?

Comment: i'm including as placed aar file in the app's libs folder.

Comment: @LokiChandu did you find any way to ship library with 3rd party libraries?

Comment: not yet found  with optimized solution..