# Why am I getting this NoClassDefFoundError even though the dependency is on my classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, executable-jar, intellij-plugin

Java code throwing the `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting Compiler4..");
            Compiler4.main(args);
            System.out.println("Compiler4 finished successfuly");

        } catch (Throwable ex) {

            System.out.println("Compiler4 threw an exception: " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();

            Throwable cause = ex.getCause();

            if (cause != null) {
                System.out.println("Cause: " + cause);
                cause.printStackTrace();                
            }

            System.out.println("End of Compiler4 exception");
        }
    }

}
```

Compiler4.java imports the right package name for Disposable class:

```
import com.intellij.openapi.Disposable;
```

Classpath:

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
./tmp/lcc4/util.jar
```

Disposable is found in jar:

```
$ jar -tf ./tmp/lcc4/util.jar | grep Disposable.class
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4g
com/intellij/openapi/Disposable.class
```

Disposable is found by `java` command (It's OK that it does not have a `main()` method):

```
java com/intellij/openapi/Disposable
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4g
Error: Main method not found in class com.intellij.openapi.Disposable, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

One would think it should run correctly, but it does not:

```
java -jar lcc4.jar 
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4g
Starting Compiler4..
Compiler4 threw an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/openapi/Disposable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/openapi/Disposable
    at com.dreambox.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.openapi.Disposable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.openapi.Disposable
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.openapi.Disposable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.dreambox.Main.main(Main.java:12)
End of Compiler4 exception
```

I am on Mac.

Comment: have you tried `java -cp $CLASSPATH -jar lcc4.jar`?

Comment: Just did. Same result.

Comment: I would try adding the complete path of util.jar to the Class-Path manifest entry in your lcc4.jar.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Main%20Attributes for more info on this.

Comment: @JerryOberle, that worked! Now I am confused. Don't Jars use normal $CLASSPATH?

Comment: @IrinaRapoport, no, apparently they do not.  See the description of the -jar option to the java program itself, in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html  It says that "When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored."

Comment: Thank you! That was very valuable. That's the complete answer, in comments.

Comment: Now looking for a way to embed jars in jars

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar

Comment: @ScottSosna I've seen those, but they are old.