# Calling class of a jar inside the lib folder of a jar from command line?

Tags: java, cmd

I am making a maven project which contains a dependency with runtime scope. I want to call this jar class directly from command line. I don't have the option to make fat jar. My Jar structure is:-

```
one.jar
--- temp.class
.....
.....
/lib/two.jar
/lib/three.jar
```

suppose I want to call Temp1 class of two.jar directly from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

**java -cp "path" "classname"**

eg : java -cp C:\one.jar com.test.main.temp

**OR**

java -cp /usr/local/jar/one.jar:/some/other/two.jar com.your.main.classname

Comment: No this doesn't work. I am trying to call the two.jar which is inside the one.jar. Which is not directly called from one.jar and namespace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar

this might help you

Comment: java -cp /usr/local/jar/test1.jar:/some/other/test2.jar com.your.main.classname

Comment: I already tried this approach. Please let me know if u are tested this approach on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

you could place a "proxy" class in one.jar which delegates to the target class in your embedded two.jar