# java Jar containing jars => java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError -> How to include .jar files

Tags: java, jar

jar file

[image]

when I run `java -jar main.jar` I get the following error:
[image]

The main class of the .jar file `second.jar` which is one of several libraries inside is not accessible.

I cannot rebuild the project since I just have the `main.jar` file.

How can I write a `run.bat` file or a `mainifest.mf` file that all .jar files that are contained in the `main.jar` file are accessible.

Here is the `mainifest.mf` file inside the `main.jar`:

[image]

Comment: Just include the dependencies in classpath by using -cp flag.    java -cp dirToDependencyJars -jar main.jar

Comment: And what is the directory if the jars are inside the main folder of the main jar ?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't notice that you had embedded jars. Here's a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar

Answer (score 0):

There are following probable options for you to solve.

1. Add all the required jar files in the Manifest.MF as given below.

> ```
> Manifest-Version: 1.0
> Main-Class: com.comapany.product.MainClass
> Class-Path: a.jar b.jar c.jar
> ```

2. You can run manually using the following command

> java -cp a.jar;b.jar;c.jar com.comapany.product.MainClass

3. It is highly recommended to create a fat jar using Maven Shade plugin in case of Maven or Shadow plugin in case of Gradle.