# run .jar file which has dependency with another .jar file in command line

Tags: java, postgresql, command-line, dependencies, executable-jar

I have a .jar file(insertdata.jar) which has a dependency with postgresql-42.2.23.jar.I have included main class in the Manifest file also. Currently both of these files are located inside C:\Users\yush\Desktop\java directory. I have tried to run insertdata1.jar file with following command in the command line.

> **java -jar C:\Users\yush\Desktop\java\insertdata1.jar**

with this command I'm getting following error, which seems it is unable to access postgresql-42.2.23.jar classes.

> **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver**

My question is how do I run insertdata1.jar file in the command line with postgresql-42.2.23.jar?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't.  `java -jar ...` doesn't allow you to tinker with the classpath.  For alternative approaches (that will work), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar

Answer (score 1):

2 options for you

1. change your invocation
   `java -cp <class-path-of-all-required-jars> <Main.class>`
2. build uber/fat jar - combines all individual jars. then you can so your -jar thing